# How to write Dockerfile for Render.com deployment

Tags: java, spring-boot, dockerfile, render.com

I wrote sample Java spring boot code like this.
https://github.com/hardreggaecafe/java_spring_boot_sample

And everytime I deploy this code to Render.com, it fails.
Dockerfile is here.

```
FROM maven:3.8.2-jdk-11 AS build
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean package -Pprod -DskipTests
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
COPY --from=build /target/backendaccountant-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar demo.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [“java”,“-jar”,“demo.jar”]
```

Error log is like this.

```
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.5.0/plexus-utils-3.5.0.jar (267 kB at 6.4 MB/s)
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 13.84 Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-compiler-javac/2.13.0/plexus-compiler-javac-2.13.0.jar (23 kB at 518 kB/s)
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.03 [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :dependency
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.03 [INFO] Compiling 3 source files with javac [debug release 17] to target/classes
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [INFO] Total time:  11.972 s
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-15T06:30:33Z
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [WARNING] The requested profile "prod" could not be activated because it does not exist.
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project QuickMaster: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported -> [Help 1]
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [ERROR]
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [ERROR]
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.33 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c mvn clean package -Pprod -DskipTests" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  ------
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM   > [build 3/3] RUN mvn clean package -Pprod -DskipTests:
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-15T06:30:33Z
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [WARNING] The requested profile "prod" could not be activated because it does not exist.
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project QuickMaster: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported -> [Help 1]
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [ERROR]
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [ERROR]
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.33 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  ------
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  Dockerfile:3
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  --------------------
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM     1 |     FROM maven:3.8.2-jdk-11 AS build
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM     2 |     COPY . .
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM     3 | >>> RUN mvn clean package -Pprod -DskipTests
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM     4 |     FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM     5 |     COPY --from=build /target/backendaccountant-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar demo.jar
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  --------------------
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  error: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c mvn clean package -Pprod -DskipTests" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  error: exit status 1
```

So what can I do? Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `release version 17 not supported` is pretty clear. Use a JDK17 image, you are now using a JDK11 image, which obviously won't support Java 17.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. After replaced maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17, this error is clear but encounter next error. Will post another issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Dockerfile` uses the following declaration

```
FROM maven:3.8.2-jdk-11 AS build
```

Which means it will pull in a Docker Image with JDK11.

The error you get

```
project QuickMaster: Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported -> [Help 1]
Aug 15 03:30:33 PM  #11 14.32 [ERROR]
```

Indicates you need to use JDK17 instead of JDK11. So use a newer Docker image. Something like

```
FROM maven:3-eclipse-temurin-17 AS build
```

Even if compilation would succeed running would fail as that will, obviously, also require JDK17, where you now also have JDK11.

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
```

Should be something like

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-alpine
```

Your whole Dockerfile should look something like this

```
FROM maven:3-eclipse-temurin-17 AS build
COPY . .
RUN mvn clean package -Pprod -DskipTests
FROM eclipse-temurin:17-alpine
COPY --from=build /target/backendaccountant-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar demo.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [“java”,“-jar”,“demo.jar”]
```

This will use JDK17 for both the build as well as running the application.

Comment: Oh, Thank you! It helps. But another error occurs. Please see above.

Comment: Which is another question, don't shoehorn multiple questions into 1.

Comment: I did notice your running was also JDK11, I dupdated the answer to also fix that (both need to be JDK17).

Comment: Super thatnks. I posted another issue and I can understand what happened.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @M. Deinum.
I changed Dockerfile first line to below. It clear this error.

```
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17 AS build
```